# Laravel multiple value validation required one

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i have 3 columns in my table; admin_id, server_id and client_id. Only one is required. For example, if i send admin_id, server_id and client_id are not required. Or if i send server_id, client_id and admin_id are not required. But i can not send empty all of them. Also i can not send client_id and admin_id at the same time or other possibilities. I have to send only one of them.

How can i validate ?

```
$rules = [
    'admin_id'    => 'required|exists:admins,id',
    'server_id '  => 'required|exists:servers,id',
    'client_id '  => 'required|exists:clients,id'
];
```

If i do like this, i have to send all of them. But i just want to 1 required.

I want to check;

> if admin_id and server_id is empty; client_id is required.
>
> if client_id and server_id is empty; admin_id is required.
>
> if admin_id and client_id is empty; server_id is required.

Comment: see laravel documentation [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#conditionally-adding-rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Comment: Have you tried Require without all... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all

Comment: There is case when same time server_id, client_id, admin_id is not empty??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need `required_without_all` [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-without-all)

```
$rules = [
    'admin_id'    => 'required_without_all:server_id,client_id|exists:admins,id',
    'server_id '  => 'required_without_all:admin_id,client_id|exists:servers,id',
    'client_id '  => 'required_without_all:server_id,admin_id|exists:clients,id'
];
```

> required_without_all:foo,bar,...
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are not present.